# Запуск двух скриптов одновременно - Python

Tags: python

У меня есть два скрипта:
tgbot.py и keyboard_catcher.py

Первый - телеграмм бот, второй - захват клавиатуры.
Мне нужно, чтобы пока захватывалась клавиатура, в фоне работал бот.

Проблема в том, что если запустить их последовательно, работает либо только бот, либо только захват :(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну запустите две командных строки отдельно и там эти скрипты. Ну либо если они как-то между собой должны быть связаны, то показывайте хотя бы схематически ваш код.